# Automating Kibana Dashboard Creation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am working on a project and I need to insert some of Kibana Graphs in the app.
I've created a Kibana Dashboard using a JSON file, to visualize the index a specific index from Elasticsearch.
I want to automatize the creation of the Dashboard to use it with different indexes.  Elasticsearch/ Kibana 7.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure there is a more elegant way, but what you can do is:

1. Export the dashboard(s) and include the related objects under: Management -> Saved Objects
   [image]
2. Edit the exported .ndjson file. For example if you are building on the index pattern `filebeat-*` search for that and replace it with whatever you want to change it to.
3. Reimport the .ndjson file under Import in the Saved Objects.

Comment: Thank you, and what about Grafana as an alternative?

Comment: I don't know Grafana well enough to know that unfortunately.

Comment: This isn't exactly automated. The import and export feature can be done via REST